# Running Exoplayer Audio In The Background

Tags: android

I'm trying to make the Exoplayer play audio as a background service. I'm running the version 2.7.3 so, this function isn't built in as in the later releases. Also, I'm using API 21 so, I can't have a foreground process.

What I have done is created a service class, which runs my PlayerActivity, but that doesn't work.

Service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        int id = Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getExtras()).getInt("id");
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class);
        newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        newIntent.putExtra("id",id);
        startActivity(newIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My player class:

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExoPlayer player;
    PlayerView playerView;
    private long playbackPosition;
    private int currentWindow;
    private boolean playWhenReady;
    BottomNavigationView navigation;
    SQLite db = new SQLite(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        playerView.setShowShuffleButton(true);
        playerView.setUseArtwork(true);

        navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        // Ensure correct menu item is selected (where the magic happens)
        Menu menu = navigation.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(2);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    startActivity(new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    startActivity(new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, SearchDownload.class));
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    startActivity(new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, PlayerActivity.class));
                    return true;
            }
            finish();
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void initializePlayer() {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
                new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());

        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);


        File yourDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()+"/Capriccio");
        String name = "";
        int id = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getInt("id");
        // if a playlist selected
        final ArrayList<PlayListResult> songList = db.GetPlayListSongList(id);

        if(songList.size() == 0) {

            File[] files = yourDir.listFiles();
            for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
                if (f.isFile())
                    name = f.getName();
                Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Do your stuff
            }
            Uri[] uri = new Uri[files.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                uri[i] = Uri.parse(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
            MediaSource[] mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
            MediaSource sources = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSource);
            player.prepare(sources, true, false);
        }
        else{
            Uri[] uri = new Uri[songList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < songList.size(); i++) {
                uri[i] = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()
                        + songList.get(i).getAbsoluteSongPath$app_debug());
            }
            MediaSource[] mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
            MediaSource sources = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSource);
            player.prepare(sources, true, false);
        }
        player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.DefaultEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections){
                int a  = player.getCurrentPeriodIndex();
                if (songList.size() != 0){

                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(songList.get(a).getThumbnailUrl$app_debug());
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    try {
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    playerView.setDefaultArtwork(bmp);


                    String text= "text " + a;
                    Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this,text,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }
        });
    }
    private MediaSource[] buildMediaSource(Uri[] uri) {
        MediaSource[] sources = new MediaSource[uri.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < uri.length; i++) {
            DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(uri[i]);
            final FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource();
            try {
                fileDataSource.open(dataSpec);
            } catch (FileDataSource.FileDataSourceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DataSource.Factory factory = new DataSource.Factory() {
                @Override
                public DataSource createDataSource() {
                    return fileDataSource;
                }
            };
            sources[i] = new ExtractorMediaSource(fileDataSource.getUri(),
                    factory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
        }
        return sources;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        hideSystemUi();
        if ((Util.SDK_INT <= 23 || player == null)) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void hideSystemUi() {
        playerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23) {
            releasePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            releasePlayer();
        }
    }
    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            playbackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
            currentWindow = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
            playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

}
```

I did expect this to do the trick as I was hoping the activity would be running as a Service, but I guess I should try to put only a part of the player in the service, though not sure which and how.